# struggling minimizing non linear function

Tags: numpy, scipy

I am looking forward to minimize a non linear function with 3 arguments (`x1`,`x2` and `x3`)

My sources of information are:

- the explanation of the minimization function: 
  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html
- And an example they provide:
  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html

I do not belong to a mathematical area, so first off forgive me if I am using incorrect wording / expressions.

This is my code :

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def rosen(x1,x2,x3):
    return np.sqrt(((x1**2)*0.002)+((x2**2)*0.0035)+((x3**2)*0.0015)+(2*x1*x2*0.015)+(2*x1*x3*0.01)+(2*x2*x3*0.02))
```

I think that the first step is okey up to here..

Then it is required to state the:

```
x0 : ndarray
Initial guess. len(x0) is the dimensionality of the minimization problem.
```

Given that I am stating 3 args in the minimization function I shall state a 3 dim array , such like this?

```
x0=np.array([1,1,1])

res = minimize(rosen, x0)
print(res.x)
```

The undesired output is:

```
rosen() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'x2' and 'x3'
```

Which I do not really understand where shall I state the positional arguments.

Apart from that I would like to set some bounds for the outputing values for `x1`,`x2`,`x3` .

Which I tried

```
res = minimize(rosen, x0,  bounds=([0,None]),options={"disp": False})
```

Which outputs also that :

```
ValueError: length of x0 != length of bounds
```

How should I then express the bounds inside the `res` then?

The desired output would be simply to output an array for `x1`,`x2`,`x3` according to the minimization of the function where each value is minimun 0, as stated in the bounds and that the sum of the args add up to 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Function-definition

Read the docs carefully, e.g. for your function-def:

> fun : callable
>
> ```
> The objective function to be minimized. Must be in the form f(x, *args). The
> optimizing argument, x, is a 1-D array of points, and args is a tuple of any
> additional fixed parameters needed to completely specify the function.
> ```

Your function should take a 1d-array, while you implement the multi-argument for multi-variables approach!

Changing:

```
def rosen(x1,x2,x3):
    return np.sqrt(((x1**2)*0.002)+((x2**2)*0.0035)+((x3**2)*0.0015)+(2*x1*x2*0.015)+(2*x1*x3*0.01)+(2*x2*x3*0.02))

def rosen(x):
    x1,x2,x3 = x # unpack vector for your kind of calculations
    return np.sqrt(((x1**2)*0.002)+((x2**2)*0.0035)+((x3**2)*0.0015)+(2*x1*x2*0.015)+(2*x1*x3*0.01)+(2*x2*x3*0.02))
```

should work. This is a bit a *repair-something-to-keep-my-other-code* approach but won't hurt much in this example. Usually you implement your function-definition on the 1d-array-input assumption!

#### Bounds

Again from the docs:

> bounds : sequence, optional
>
> ```
> Bounds for variables (only for L-BFGS-B, TNC and SLSQP). (min, max) pairs for each
> element in x, defining the bounds on that parameter. Use None for one of min or max
> when there is no bound in that direction.
> ```

So you need `n_vars` pairs! Easily achieved by using a list-comprehension, deducing the necessary info from `x0`.

```
res = minimize(rosen, x0,  bounds=[[0,None] for i in range(len(x0))],options={"disp": False})
```

#### Make variables sum up to 1 / Constraints

Your comment implies you want the variables to sum up to 1. You would need to use an equality-constraint then (only 1 solver supporting this and inequality-constraints; one other only inequality-constraints; the rest no constraints; solver will be picked automatically if none explicitly given).

It looks somewhat like:

```
cons = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x:  sum(x) - 1})  # read docs to understand!
                                                       # to think about:
                                                       # sum vs. np.sum
                                                       # (not much diff here)
res = minimize(rosen, x0,  bounds=[[0,None] for i in range(len(x0))],options={"disp": False}, constraints=cons)
```

For the case of x nonnegative, the constraint is usually called the probability-simplex.

(untested code; conceptually correct!)

Comment: Thank you so much! I have 1 more question: is there anyway I could state (in the res for example as an argument)  that the addtion of the args `x1`,`x2`,`x3`add up to 1? I am able to find it

Comment: Yes, by using constraints. Look up the example. In this case (eq-constraints) only 1 solver to use is left and will be picked automatically, SLSQP. Constraints are more troublesome than other parts usually (because many people ignore smoothness and co; but yours, called the probability-simplex is simple and i think the examples do have this one too!)